# jpa join query on a subclass

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have the following relationships in JPA (hibernate).

Object X has two subclasses, Y and Z.

Object A has a manyToOne relationship to object X. (Note, this is a one-sided relationship so object X cannot see object A).

Now, I want to get the max value of a column in object A, but only where the relationship is of a specific subtype, ie...Y.

So, that equates to...get the max value of column1 in object A, across all instances of A where they have a relationship with Y. Is this possible? I'm a bit lost as how to query it.

I was thinking of something like:

```
String query = "SELECT MAX(a.columnName) FROM A a join a.x;
Query query = super.entityManager.createQuery(query);
query.execute();
```

However that doesn't take account of the subclass of X...so I'm a bit lost.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested it, but try something like this:

SELECT MAX(a.columnName) FROM A a join a.x WHERE a.x.class = y.class

Hope it helps,
Anton

Answer (score 15):

JPA 2.0 allows queries to restrict the classes returned from a polymorphic query with the TYPE operator. From the JPA 2.0 specification:

> #### 4.6.17.4 Entity Type Expressions
>
> An entity type expression can be used
>   to restrict query polymorphism. The
>   TYPE operator returns the exact type
>   of the argument.
>
> The syntax of an entity type
>   expression is as follows:
>
> ```
> entity_type_expression ::=
>          type_discriminator |
>          entity_type_literal |
>          input_parameter
> type_discriminator ::=
>          TYPE(identification_variable |
>                 single_valued_object_path_expression |
>                 input_parameter )
> ```
>
> An **entity_type_literal** is designated
>   by the entity name.
>
> The Java class of the entity is used
>   as an input parameter to specify the
>   entity type.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> SELECT e
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) IN (Exempt, Contractor)
>
> SELECT e
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) IN (:empType1, :empType2)
>
> SELECT e
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) IN :empTypes
>
> SELECT TYPE(e)
> FROM Employee e
> WHERE TYPE(e) <> Exempt
> ```

JPA 1.0 doesn't offer such a mechanism so if you're using JPA 1.0, this won't be possible using standard JPQL.

If you don't mind using proprietary HQL, then you can use the special property `class`:

> Likewise, the special property `class` accesses the discriminator value of an instance in the case of polymorphic persistence. A Java class name embedded in the where clause will be translated to its discriminator value.
>
> ```
> from Cat cat where cat.class = DomesticCat
> ```

So in your case, I'd try something like that:

```
SELECT MAX(a.columnName) FROM A a where a.x.class = Y
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and clear answer Pascal! Really appreciate it!